# Google Sign-in with existing ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-oauth, google-signin, google-authentication

I'm trying to handle google-signin to my existing ASP.NET MVC application. It has a forms authentication developped customely and it works fine for username and password.

I want to add Google-sign-in to this project. I currently added the button, created the app in google developper console got my id and secret and set up the urls.

I can see the button in login page, click, i see my account and picture, select account.
At this point google posts me some data. I received in an Action method an string array object called "credential" which has a string in first position. But I don't know what to do from here on...

Can somebody help me with this? Which document I should use?

I'm reading this: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web  till now but i'm stuck.

What I dont want is this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on

I want to handle the requests needed myself (with cookies, database checks and keeping track of tokens) and get the user information google provides by myself in my controller's action methods.

Here is a part of the razor view code

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="my id is here"
         data-login_uri="@Url.Action("LoginWithGoogle","Login")"
         data-auto_prompt="false">
    </div>
    <div class="g_id_signin"
         data-type="standard"
         data-size="large"
         data-theme="outline"
         data-text="sign_in_with"
         data-shape="rectangular"
         data-logo_alignment="left"
         data-auto_prompt="true"
         >
    </div>
```

I added this script:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

This Action method can catch the string:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginWithGoogle(string[] credential)
{
    ViewBag.Data = credential;
    ///I will do necessary stuff here.
    return View();
}
```

Notes:

-Identity is not installed and will not be used (if unless impossible without using it).

-My .Net Framework version: 4.7.2

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Its hard to give you any advice without your current code.

Comment: Let me add them into the question

Comment: I'm just wondering what is next? I should send this string to google in another request and it should give me some information abut the user (i think) but could not find where and how.

Comment: Your going to have issues following that sample as Google+ API was shut down in 2019.

Comment: I don't want the google+ I want the new Google id services, is the link wrong?

Comment: Are you using AspNetCore.Identity? [Here's a sample](https://github.com/MintPlayer/ExternalAuthentication) and [here's a project](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer). If you aren't using Identity it'll be harder to implement it all yourself.

Comment: I'm not using dot net core at all, its framework 4.7.2. I also don't use Identity framework.

Comment: I think you best bet would be to upgrade to a  post .net core version.   That being said  to check this [External Authentication Services with ASP.NET Web API (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services).   You may be lucky and find it works i have my doubts.   A lot of things have changed in resent years you may have to reinvent the wheel on this one to get it to work.   Save some time and upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and you are right about this but its a legacy code that does not belong to me, and the bugget is only for only adding google login. I'm checking the link you sent me now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use "full" default auth code too, here is how I handle Google/Yandex/Discord/OAuth response:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string? returnUrl = null)
{
    var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), null, new { returnUrl });
    var properties = signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
}

[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string? returnUrl = null)
{
    var info = await signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (info == null)
    {
        return this.Redirect(LoginPath);
    }

    var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
    var name = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name) ?? info.Principal.Identity.Name;

    // your own actions & checks with email, name etc
```

This still required some "default" preparations in Startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, UserStoreService.UserRole>()
    .AddUserStore<UserStoreService>()
    .AddRoleStore<UserStoreService>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(...)
```

But here `User` is my own class, `UserRole` is own (end empty) class, and `UserStoreService` is my own implementation of `IDisposable, IUserStore<User>, IUserEmailStore<User>, IUserClaimStore<User>, IUserSecurityStampStore<User>, IRoleStore<UserStoreService.UserRole>` (you may modify this list according to your needs)

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. I think yours is .net core and im using the framework in this project.

Answer (score 0):

This is example how to process external authentication using owin. First of all, you have to setup your startup.cs and update configuration with something like this. Of course you have to import required packages into your project.

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ....

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "YourGoogleClientId",
            ClientSecret = "YourGoogleClientSecret",
        });
    }
```

Then in your account controller (example name) create method that will handle your login with google button. For example:

```
    public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider)
    {
        var returnUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/Account/ExternalLoginCallback";

        return new ChallengeResult(provider, returnUrl);
    }
```

Create your ChallengeResult method:

```
internal class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
{
    public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUrl)
    {
        LoginProvider = provider;
        RedirectUri = redirectUrl;
    }

    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
    public string RedirectUri { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };

        var owin = context.HttpContext.GetOwinContext();

        owin.Authentication.Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
    }
}
```

Add your new authentication method in your account controller. For example:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
    {

        try
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

            if (loginInfo == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginInfo.Email))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailed", "WebAccount");
            }
            else
            {
            // handle external login, means process user login in your system
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // handle possible exceptions
        }

        return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailed", "WebAccount");
    }

    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but i think yours also dot net core (or am I missing something in old fashioned dot net mvc?)

Comment: This is not core. Its net mvc.

Comment: I found these links after your this comment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/app-startup-differences and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana I was thinking startups.cs does not exist in framework mvc but it can apparently. Let me try this and I will let you know. Thank you.

Comment: It exists if you are using owin for example. I am maintaining some  apps that are using mvc5 and external logins. Individual accounts or custom login system. Doesnt matter. This pattern works for both.